# Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting following error while trying to use pdf.h and pdf.mm in my application.

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/aditya/Desktop/PDFStudy/zdll.lib, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

"_convertPDF", referenced from:

```
  -[PDFStudyViewController readPDF] in PDFStudyViewController.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 4):

This is because your library `/Users/aditya/Desktop/PDFStudy/zdll.lib` was compiled for other architectures, for example, `arm6` or `arm7` used in iPhones.

You are probably testing your app in simulator, which requires library to be compiled for architecture `i386`.

Comment: And static libraries can be universal too, so you can have one .lib that the compiler can use for both i386 and ARM builds if you create it correctly. So I'd recommend the originating poster investigate their build settings if building zdll.lib themselves, or else consult with whoever did build it.

Comment: Where did you get that library?