# Xcode: Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Honestly, I'm quite inexperienced in OBJ-C.
I've looked for a solution on Stack Overflow and other pages very hard but I'm still not able to fix my issue.
For my final project in school I have to program an iOS-App which should be able to display data from a MySQL-database. I checked out an article of *Code with Chris* (http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/#creatingphpservice) and tried to modify it for my specifications from school.

So here's my error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Data", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in HomeModel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As I already found out this means something like my HomeModel-File wants to access to my "Data"-class which I defined in "Data.h". But I have already imported "Data.h" into my "HomeModel.m" (and also to "HomeModel.h" although this is unnecessary I think).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

PS: I already checked the "Compile Sources" of my project.

Comment: You need to ensure that `Data.m` is selected for your target.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correct the "Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "\_main" linking issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049731/how-do-i-correct-the-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-main-linking-i)

Comment: @rmaddy: You mean that I have to ensure that "Data.m" is already added to the "Compile Sources" of my project, right? In case you mean that...yes, I have already checked that.

Comment: Does Data.m have the line `@implementation Data`?

Comment: @rmaddy: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem!

Comment: What did you have in your Data.m file?

Comment: Just take a look at the answer that I've added, it's very embarrassing :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture i386:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304192/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Thanks a lot for your answers and comments!

As I already mentioned I'm really no expert in Obj-C and of course it was a very **stupid** mistake...

My "Data.m" was completely empty.

I just had to add these few lines:

```
#import "Data.h"

@implementation Data
@end
```

Again: Thanks for spending your time on my **"problem"**! haha

Comment: If that's your entire Data.m, then what is the point of the class? What's in Data.h?

Comment: There is just one class named "Data" with some properties in it. I've started some days ago with this section of my project.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and this warning disappeared after changing the *Build Settings > Architectures* to **"Standard architectures"** and *Build Settings > Valid Architectures* to **"armv7 armv7s armv8 arm64"** for all the projects and targets that my project had.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope; this cannot be right as it's clear the missing class is part of the project source tree, not part of a library linked in by the project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the warning was the "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:" and looked exactly the same. Because I had distinct projects (cocoapods) and some of them had different architectures selected. Give it a try.

Comment: Yes it probably was the same, however the important information is the missing class or function symbol.  A different solution would be required if the symbol is part of the source tree or provided with a library.  The OP's is the former, and yours was the latter.